# How do I set the container user in an AzureDevops Pipeline YAML?

Tags: azure-devops

I have this yaml file that I am using with Azure DevOps to build a project on github:

```
resources:
  containers:
  - container: fedora-29
    image: fedora:29
    options: --user 0

jobs:
  - job: RunInContainer
    pool:
      vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04'
    strategy:
      matrix:
        fedora-29:
          containerResource: fedora-29

    container: $[ variables['containerResource'] ]

    steps:
    - bash: |
        dnf install 'dnf-command(copr)' -y
      timeoutInMinutes: 30
```

This yaml files uses a `fedora:29` container. Fedora 29 doesn't include `sudo` out of the box and uses a non-root user by default.

So the `dnf` command fails:

```
Error: This command has to be run under the root user.
```

If I add a `sudo` before `dnf`, the error is:

```
line 1: sudo: command not found
```

Is there a way to do the equivalent of the `USER` command in a Dockerfile via the yaml file? Or can I pass the `--user 0` flag to `docker run` somehow?

Comment: all the "things" you specify in `options` would be sent to the docker daemon as arguments, so probably?

Comment: I tested the above file (including the `options: --user 0` part). It doesn't work. azure forces a user with userid 1001.

Comment: well, launch your own container in that case, if azure forces a user 1001 nothing you can do about it